# Drawing image to canvas in metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, imagebrush

I've been trying to draw an image onto a canvas in my metro app but nothing has appeared so far. Here is my code:

```
    Rectangle blueRectangle = new Rectangle();
        blueRectangle.Height = 100;
        blueRectangle.Width = 200;
        ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush();
        imgBrush.ImageSource = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\dock.jpg"));
        blueRectangle.Fill = imgBrush;
        paintCanvas.Children.Add(blueRectangle);
```

When I use the line

```
      blueRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

instead of the one using the ImageBrush I get a blue rectangle like I intended so I think I must be doing something wrong with the ImageBrush.

I plan on using the images as sprites in a game when I learn how to draw them so I have to be able to manipulate them using c#.

Thanks for you help!

Edit:
I've changed the code to access the roaming application data but I'm still getting a file not found exception. (the file is in the correct place)

```
    ApplicationData appData = ApplicationData.Current;

        try
        {
            StorageFile sourceFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/dock.jpg"));
            await sourceFile.CopyAsync(appData.RoamingFolder);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // If images have already been copied the CopyAsync() methods aboev will fail.
            // Ignore those errors.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        Rectangle blueRectangle = new Rectangle();
        blueRectangle.Height = 100;
        blueRectangle.Width = 200;

        // Create an ImageBrush
        ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush();

        imgBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///roaming/dock.png"));

        // Fill rectangle with an ImageBrush
        blueRectangle.Fill = imgBrush;
        //blueRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        paintCanvas.Children.Add(blueRectangle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. Here's what I have for code now.

```
StorageFile file;
StorageFolder InstallationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;      

string filePath = @"Assets\dock.jpg";
file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync(filePath);
IRandomAccessStream dockpic = await file.OpenAsync(0);
BitmapImage dockimage = new BitmapImage();
dockimage.SetSource(dockpic);

Rectangle blueRectangle = new Rectangle();
blueRectangle.Height = 100;
blueRectangle.Width = 200;
// Create an ImageBrush
ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush();
imgBrush.ImageSource = dockimage;

// Fill rectangle with an ImageBrush
blueRectangle.Fill = imgBrush;
paintCanvas.Children.Add(blueRectangle);
```

I ended up using a StorageFolder and created the BitmapImage using a Stream instead of from a uri.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access local data in that way from a Metro style app.  See this article on [accessing local data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh758319%28v=win.10%29.aspx) and this [Application data sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2) for ways you can access local data.

Comment: Thanks for that sample. I've tried using that method to access the app's roaming data but I'm getting a FileNotFoundException.